# Access child Object in js

Tags: javascript, hierarchy

```
function Luminary(radius, orbitRadius, speed, children) {
    this.radius = radius;
    this.orbitRadius = orbitRadius;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.children = children;
}

function initSolarSystem() {
    var moon = new Luminary(0.02, 0.2, 0.0015, []);
    var earth = new Luminary(0.1, 0.7, 0.001, [moon]);
    var sun = new Luminary(0.3, 0.0, 0.0, [earth]);
    return sun;
}

var solarSystem = initSolarSystem();
```

1. I have the code above in JS. How can I access for example the radius of earth using the **solarSystem** object? The following returns **Undefined**
   `alert(solarSystem.children.radius);`
2. How should I call children in a recursive function as follows:

   ```
   function draw(obj) {
       // draw Current Object 
       if (obj.children != undefined) {
         draw(obj.children);
       }
   }

   draw(solarSystem);
   ```

Can Someone please help me?

Comment: `solarySystem.children[0].radius`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have the code above in JS. How can I access for example the radius
>   of earth using the solarSystem object? The following returns Undefined
>   alert(solarSystem.children.radius);

`solarSystem.children` is an array, so use `solarSystem.children[0].radius`

> How should I call children in a recursive function as follows.

```
function draw(obj) 
{
  // draw Current Object

  if (obj.children != undefined) 
  {
    obj.children.forEach( s => draw(s) ); //invoke draw in a loop
    //draw(obj.children[0]); //use 
  }
}

draw(solarSystem);
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all your `.children` is an array. so call `.children[i].radius`.
Second:

> ```
> if (obj.children != undefined) {
>   draw(obj.children);
> }
> ```

You call here once the draw function for the full `children` array. So you need to implement a for loop.

For this there are a lot options this is my approach:

```js
function Luminary(name, radius, orbitRadius, speed, children = []) {
    this.name = name;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.orbitRadius = orbitRadius;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.children = children;
}

function initSolarSystem() {
    var moon = new Luminary("moon", 0.02, 0.2, 0.0015);
    var earth = new Luminary("earth", 0.1, 0.7, 0.001, [moon]);
    var sun = new Luminary("sun", 0.3, 0.0, 0.0, [earth]);
    return sun;
}

var solarSystem = initSolarSystem();

function draw(obj) {
    // Draw current object.
    for (let key in obj.children)
      if (obj.children.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        //if (typeof(obj.children) == "array") {
         console.log(obj.children[key].radius);
          draw(obj.children[key]);
        }
}

draw(solarSystem);
```